Bitbucket: Two private keys, Same account (Google Auth) different workspaces, How to setup ssh config file?
I have two bitbucket workspaces and as everyone knows, bitbucket requires separate ssh keys for both accounts (much like your password 'vas123' is already in use). I setup my .ssh/config file as follow
Host bitbucket.org
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  AddkeysToAgent yes 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

However the problem is that in order to connect to a workspace, i have to comment out the identity key of the other and save it. is it possible to work with the repos of the both workspaces without tinkering the config file?
[Update] Please note that I use the same account. There are two questions about the same issue

How to handle multiple ssh-keys
How to maintain multiple bitbucket accounts with multiple ssh keys in the same system

but they use two different accounts hence they are able to identify them separately in the config file. I cannot do that as I use one account which uses Google authentication. Think of it as one account which is given right to the workspace repository. I'm a free lancer so I do not create separate accounts for each of my clients. they just provide me access to their repositories
please see this issue on bitbucket
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-20631

You could try something similar to How to handle multiple ssh-keys

This question is similar to: How to maintain multiple bitbucket accounts with multiple ssh keys in the same system. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

updated the details describing why this one is different than the other questions

You seem to indicate that you use 2 different keys, which may give you different access rights. Is that correct ? If it is, you really are in the same situation as "How to handle multiple ssh-keys".

If you need to use the 2 different keys from the same repo, you may create 2 remotes on that repo pointing to the two different sections of your ssh_config file.

how to make them point to two different sections of ssh config file?

I think you can still use the same account with the linked approaches. Just make sure to update the remote URLs accordingly (git@KEY_IDENTIFIER:accountname/reponame.git) as stated in the answer.
